# Cache-Control : no store still showing as public,no-store in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, web-config, cache-control

I have added below code to web.config to achieve cache-control : no-store in google chrome and internet explorer.

```
 <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store" />
 <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
 <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
```

but i still see cache-control : public,no-cache,no- store in the response headers
     please help!